# customising matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot for a little module I am developing (code appended). However, I can't work out how to customise the figure (increas figure size, change background canvas colour). How do I do this. I have tried `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))` after `self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()` and this does increase the figure size and add my buttons but shows my plot on a seperate figure. What is my simple mistake?

[image]

```
    # Setup the axes.
    self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    self.slider_ax    = self.fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.03, 0.65, 0.03])
    self.delete_ax    = self.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.84, 0.1, 0.04])
    self.register_ax  = self.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.78, 0.1, 0.04])
    self.add_ax       = self.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.72, 0.1, 0.04])
    self.save_ax      = self.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.66, 0.1, 0.04])
    self.reset_ax     = self.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.16, 0.1, 0.04])
    self.quit_ax      = self.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.1,  0.1, 0.04])

    # Make the slider
   ! self.slider = Slider(self.slider_ax, 'Frame', 0, 1, 
                        valinit=0, valfmt='%1.2f', closedmin=True,
                        closedmax=False)
    self.slider.on_changed(self.update)

    #Make the buttons
    self.del_button = Button(self.delete_ax, 'Delete')
    self.del_button.on_clicked(self.delete)
    self.reg_button = Button(self.register_ax, 'Register')
    self.reg_button.on_clicked(self.register)
    self.add_button = Button(self.add_ax, "Add")
    self.add_button.on_clicked(self.add)
    self.save_button = Button(self.save_ax, "Save")
    self.save_button.on_clicked(self.save)
    self.quit_button = Button(self.quit_ax, "Quit")
    self.quit_button.on_clicked(self.quit)
    self.reset_button = Button(self.reset_ax, "Reset")
    self.reset_button.on_clicked(self.reset)


    # Plot the first slice of the image
    self.im = self.ax.imshow(np.array(raw_dicom_stack[0]), cmap = cm.gray)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[plt.subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) has `**fig_kw` that contains all the keyword arguments that can be sent to the figure (see figure doc). One of them is `figsize`. You can do

```
self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8), ...)
```

otherwise you can use figure methods once the figure is created

```
self.fig.set_size_inches(16,8, forward=True)
```

If you call `self.fig = plt.figure()` after `subplots`, correctly, a second figure shows up. And as you add all the buttons to `self.fig`, they all go to the last defined.

At last: it would be probably better to create self.ax with add_axes, to be more coherent with all the other axes and have more control on his positioning

**edit** 
(elaborate the last sentence)

`self.ax` is a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` object (the same that you would get from e.g. `plt.subplot(111), while all the buttons are added to`matplotlib.axes.Axes`objects (created with`add_axes`).

Putting axes and subplots together can give problems with the relative position of the plot with respect to the buttons and slider if the figure size is changed or the window resized.

I think that a consistent division of the space in the figure canvas, either using `axes` or `subplots`, would be better to avoid such possible problems. So I suggest either to create the plotting axes as `self.ax = fig.add_axes(...)` or to use something like [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last point on creating ax with add_axes please

Comment: @moadeep: I've added some more info. I hope that this clarify my statement

Comment: Why  does **fig_kw contain all the keyword arguments that can be sent to the figure? How can one get this information?

Comment: you can follow the links in the [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) documentation and get to the [plt.figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) documentation

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `plt.figure` will create a new figure instance. What you want to do is modify an existing figure. You can do this with the methods available on your figure instance. The two directly relevant to this question are [set_figwidth](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figwidth), [set_figheight](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figheight) and [set_facecolor](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_facecolor).

HTH

Comment: "Each call to plt.figure will create a new figure instance": that is true only if you don't specify the figure number. Otherwise it gives back focus to figure number #